# Is it legal for a UK company to withhold salary increase if employment contract change is not accepted?

Tags: united-kingdom, notice-period, salary-review

I have a UK employment contract with 2 month notice period (so far 1.5 years).

In my first year, my manager sent me an excel file with some stuff to help guide my expectations around salary raises. It includes a tab which links performance to salary and it goes like this:

- Bad: 0%
- Monitoring: 2%
- On target: 3%
- High performer: 4%
- Exceptional: 6%

I will get paid (or so I have been told) a bonus of 8.1% (out of 10% max) for a high performance year.

In December I was also told that my salary raise was going to be 2.5%

Obviously, I was very frustrated because that does not match the high performer salary raise expectations.

My manager said I was already paid a high salary and that "on my position and performance, he sees me on benchmark X and the value says it's exactly my salary +2.5%" so according to him, it's fair (and convenient).

Then, last Friday, I also received a DocuSign short letter saying that I must accept changing my notice period from 2 to 3 months because they "want to align everyone on our corporate level at 3 month notice period". In our division, we are talking about 2 engineering managers, team leaders and programmers.

In short, they want to retain people, are not willing to compensate according to the expectations that were set, give poor excuses (in my estimation) and, in the end, put me against the wall.

If I don't accept the change to a 3 month notice period, I won't get any raise at all (which is already below company average and below my performance career expectations set up by the company themselves).

This is a profitable company.

Is this legal in the UK? Should I accept it?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I spent time trying to explain. Some direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What country/jurisdiction?

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are talking about a bonus or a salary raise. You seem to be conflating them.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I update the answer to state the country: UK. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, apologies for the confusion. My point is about salary increase but I must state the bonus because that proves the company also sees me as a high performer and it's not just my vanity talking.

Comment: Bonus and salary are typically two seperate things. Bonus is for performance. Salary is for how much you are worth to the company. I can't make too much sense of the renumeration structure at your company in the facts you've presented.

Comment: Why do you care about the legality? Legal action against an employer is a lose-lose proposition. You have very little to gain and a lot to lose (ask a different question if you want more details on this). They are playing hardball with you: you either need to accept that or find a different job.

Comment: @Hilmar The legality of situations do matter, because companies can be willing to avoid legal problems if their actions are legally questionable. If a brief reading of the situation leads them to think "we are probably overstepping here", they are almost certainly likely to just turn a blind eye to the employee not changing their notice period. I don't think we should discount the fact here there could just be a confused HR person who may be unaware of agreements already in place.

Comment: "My point is about salary increase but I must state the bonus because that proves the company also sees me as a high performer..." Ok, that's fine. But my one question is. Did they lie to you? "my manager sent me an excel file with some stuff to help guide my expectations around salary raises." Notice, you said salary raises initially, not bonus. What did that excel spreadsheet say about actual raises?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, it's the bullet points in the question. That table links "High performer" with salary raise of 4%. How do you know I'm actually a high performer? You know because I'll be paid bonus as a high performer. The bonus proves that I'm a high performer. And there is a table linking performance to salary raise. So I should really get the salary raise, IMO.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro, So if they really implied you were going to have a big raise as well, I think you can't trust them anymore. Look for another employer right away. Don't quit just yet, find a new job first, then leave.

Comment: Perhaps they'd be happy with a 2.5% increase in your notice period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“Is it legal” is rarely the right question, but “what do I do about it”. If you don’t agree with the changes in the contract (I wouldn’t) and think you are underpaid anyway, then tell your manager you think he doesn’t appreciate your good work, and ask him why in his opinion you shouldn’t look for a better position elsewhere. In this case, there is little risk for you because the whole point of their action is to make you stay longer.

Answer (score 15):

The simple answer is "yes, this is almost certainly legal". Unless it was actually written *into your contract* that you are entitled to a raise every year, they are not required to give you anything; an Excel file giving "expectations" does not create a legally binding contract, and neither does a bonus.

(Of course, what is legally required and what is sensible for retaining staff can be very different things. You need to work out whether staying at this company is the right thing for your career).

Comment: thanks for sharing. I agree with your practical advice about whether I should stay with this company or not. However, am I wrong in my understanding that verbal and written forms of communication can also be legally binding be considered part of the employment contract even if they are not entitled "Contract"?

Comment: In theory, yes, unwritten contracts can be contracts, particularly if both sides have acted as if such a contract were in place. Nothing in your question feels like it gets anywhere near meeting that threshold though, and you'll probably discover lots of HR wording somewhere very carefully designed to ensure that it never does.

Comment: I'm wondering about this conclusion because, in my understanding (could be wrong), a written contract is not even necessary in order to determine if someone is legally employed e.g. a baker starts working for a bakery without papers so it's cheaper for them. Won't they be forced to give this employee their rights? How so if there's so signed contract? My point is about not needing signed contract paper for something to be legally binding. A gray area, I understand.

Comment: All right, finding that needle in a haystack may be hard but I believe such "carefully designed" words actually are there somewhere 

Comment: I somewhat dispute that it needs to form part of the contract to be valid. Agreements between parties can certainly be binding. But obviously it becomes a matter of proving these agreements.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro A baker has statutory rights, just as you have statutory rights. There are a set of minimum legal requirements that must be met. A salary increase is not one of those things.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro You'd think the company would carefully design otherwise but if you're sure then go ahead and get a lawyer to take a look.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: The law has no notion of a "binding agreement" which is somehow not a contract. Either it's a binding contract, or it's just words. There's no middle ground. It is reasonably likely that OP's employment contract contains some sort of integration clause (i.e. "this contract constitutes the entire agreement between [company name] and the undersigned employee" or words to that effect), and so it being part of the contract, or a separate contract in its own right, is rather unlikely.

Comment: @Kevin I mean part of THE work contract which was initially signed. Agree that they would form contracts in their own right, but I didn't want to confuse matters.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: An Excel file (or any other document) sent via email, with no reply, has no consideration, no acceptance, no meeting of the minds, and is clearly not a contract.

Comment: @Kevin Where did I say that the excel spreadsheet was binding? The answer said the only source of legal obligation is the employment contract, which is simply not true. Which is what I dispute.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're on minimum wage, there's no legal right to a pay rise.  So if they want to tie your pay rise to a change of contract, they can.

If they are canny, the pay they are offering will be matched to your industry norms for an employee at your grade.  The profitability of the company isn't really a factor in that.  It can be a problem if you hit the top of the salary range for your grade.  No more significant pay rises without a promotion. That reference salary range will be completely unrelated to what you want or expect.

Answer (score 1):

> If I don't accept the change to a 3 month notice period, I won't get
> any raise at all

But if you do accept the 3 months notice period, your leverage for getting a raise (and a bonus) next year also gets weakened. You need to take this into account also.

If they've misled you in the past, and it sounds like they have, I don't think you should entangle yourself with them even more. And with a 2.5% raise, you're not even keeping up with inflation.

At this point if I were you, I would be sending out my resume to absolutely anyone and everyone. I know you didn't want to leave, but it doesn't sound like they're giving you much of a choice.

Comment: For senior positions 3 months notice period is common in the UK. Most companies recruiting into these positions accept that they will need to wait up to these periods.

Comment: @Dave3of5, Ok, I took that part off.